# Flex nav not aligning

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Okay so I'm in the process of learning flexbox but I cannot understand why my navigation title is above the links.

HTML:

```
<style>
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700);
    .box {
      display: flex;
    }

    .item {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      margin: auto;
      color: #fff;
    }

    nav {
      font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
      display: flex;
      min-width: 100%;
      background-color: #181818;
    }
    nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
        max-width: 960px
    }
    nav a {
      display: block;
      padding: 1rem;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: 400;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    nav a:hover {
      color: #343434;
    }

    .title {
      margin: 0 35px 0 10px;
      color: #1BC;
    }

                </style>    

    <nav>
        <div class="container">
      <a class="title">Architect</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Container CSS:

```
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto:
  max-width: 1200px;
}
```

Code Pen Link: http://codepen.io/ZoidCraft/pen/XKMewy

I would like the title "Architect" to be align to the left of the links.

Comment: It's because `<a class="title">Architect</a>` is not a child of your `nav ul` and it has `display: block;`.

Comment: Change your `.box` rule to `.container` ... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWJmXm

Comment: Id did that so it would be visible once I makde a toggle nav but ill see if I can make it a child of the nav. :D @zgood

Answer (score 0):

You set `<a class="title">Architect</a>` to `display: block;` in your css. Block level elements will take up their own line. `display: flex;` elements will also take up their own line.

To fix your problem you could first remove that `display: block;` from your `nav a` style. Then change your `nav ul` from `display: flex;` to `display: inline-flex;`. Now you just need to add some padding back to your `nav` since everything is display inline now, so add `padding: 1em 0;` to your `nav`

Here is an updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NrpYMz) of what I am talking about.

Comment: Why all that trouble when OP only need to fix a name reference issue in the CSS, by changing `.box` to `.container` ?

Comment: @LGSon how do you that's the issue? Also that might be troublesome if he is using bootstrap. it would make all `.row`'s flex items. He doesn't even use `.box` or `.container` in his HTML sample.

Comment: Then have a look in his codepen and you'll see what I am talking about (this one is the updated by me using only the fix I suggested): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWJmXm